# Problem with Saving and Loading cookies with SeleniumBase

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, cookies, seleniumbase

I'm trying to save the authentication of my account on Discord and the file successfully saved the cookies after I logged in but when I tried to load the cookies It didn't change the cookies at all and It asked me to log in again this problem happened with raw selenium as well don't provide a solution with pickle package I tried everything only worked with playwright package and I hope I find solution with seleniumbase

```html
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__)

class MyTestClass(BaseCase):
    def test_swag_labs(self):
        self.open("https://discord.com/")
        self.sleep(5)
        # self.save_cookies(name="cookies.txt")
        self.load_cookies(name="cookies.txt")
        self.open("https://discord.com/channels/@me")
        self.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving and loading cookies might not be enough to recreate the state. A better option would be setting a custom `user_data_dir` for the tests, and then reusing that `user_data_dir` for later tests.

With the SeleniumBase `pytest` format, you can set it via command-line option:

```bash
pytest --user-data-dir=my_data_dir
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Michael, It works fine now, I know you're the one who created the seleniumbase I saw your videos on YouTube when I was searching for bypass Cloudflare, I encourage you to keep developing the package for me it is the best automation package in the market right now so thank you so much and keep it up

Comment: Great! Thank you. Be sure to mark the answer as the "Accepted" solution on Stack Overflow.